# Hypelerdger Indy Node - Seed value

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I am playing with indy-sdk and in walkthrough demo in step 3 (https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/docs/getting-started/indy-walkthrough.md#step-3-getting-the-ownership-for-stewards-verinym) the seed value for Steward sets equal to '000000000000000000000000Steward1'.

If I change it(or leave it empty), I am getting an error. Also, in /tmp/indy/poo1.txn there is no information about this specific value.

My question is how did we know that this is the right value and how we could get it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Why it doesn't work

`000000000000000000000000Steward1` is seed which (given default key derivation method) generates DID `Th7MpTaRZVRYnPiabds81Y`. You can verify yourself using `indy-cli` ([command line tool](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/tree/master/cli))

```
indy> wallet create test key=123
Wallet "test" has been created

indy> wallet open test key=123
Wallet "test" has been opened

wallet(test):indy> did new seed=000000000000000000000000Steward1
Did "Th7MpTaRZVRYnPiabds81Y" has been created with "~7TYfekw4GUagBnBVCqPjiC" verkey
```

In the network you are using, the owner of DID `VsKV7grR1BUE29mG2Fm2kX` (ie. whoever has knowledge about its associated private key or seed) has `steward` role which grants permissions to do various operations on the ledger. So if you modify the seed, it will generate different DID which won't have required permissions to execute operations used further in the tutorial (like writing data on the ledger).

### Where is `000000000000000000000000Steward1` coming from

From what you say I presume you are using prebuilt docker image from indy-sdk repo running pool of `indy-node` instances in it, following some of these [instructions.](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk#how-to-start-local-nodes-pool-with-docker) 
So the simple answer is that configuration for `000000000000000000000000Steward1` is pre-baked in it. Look at the [dockerfile](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/ci/indy-pool.dockerfile) used for building indy-pool image. Notice these lines

```
RUN awk '{if (index($1, "NETWORK_NAME") != 0) {print("NETWORK_NAME = \"sandbox\"")} else print($0)}' /etc/indy/indy_config.py> /tmp/indy_config.py
RUN mv /tmp/indy_config.py /etc/indy/indy_config.py
```

Let's look what's in these files

```
docker exec indylocalhost cat '/etc/indy/indy_config.py'
# Current network

# Disable stdout logging
enableStdOutLogging = False

# Directory to store ledger.
LEDGER_DIR = '/var/lib/indy'

# Directory to store logs.
LOG_DIR = '/var/log/indy'

# Directory to store keys.
KEYS_DIR = '/var/lib/indy'

# Directory to store genesis transactions files.
GENESIS_DIR = '/var/lib/indy'

# Directory to store backups.
BACKUP_DIR = '/var/lib/indy/backup'

# Directory to store plugins.
PLUGINS_DIR = '/var/lib/indy/plugins'

# Directory to store node info.
NODE_INFO_DIR = '/var/lib/indy'
NETWORK_NAME = 'sandbox'%
```

This

```
# Directory to store genesis transactions files.
GENESIS_DIR = '/var/lib/indy'
```

Looks like what we are looking for. Let's see what's there

```
docker exec indylocalhost ls '/var/lib/indy/sandbox'
data
domain_transactions_genesis
keys
node1_additional_info.json
node1_info.json
node1_version_info.json
node2_additional_info.json
node2_info.json
node2_version_info.json
node3_additional_info.json
node3_info.json
node3_version_info.json
node4_additional_info.json
node4_info.json
node4_version_info.json
pool_transactions_genesis
```

In blockchains, genesis file is typically the file you use to initially kick off the network and may populate network with some data. In case of hyperledger-indy, there's 4 "subledgers" which contain different types of transactions: `domain`, `pool`, `config`, `audit`. The `domain` subledger is the one which contains things such like `DID`s, credential schema or credential definitons. We are looking for a DID, so let's look at file domain genesis file.

```
docker exec indylocalhost cat '/var/lib/indy/sandbox/domain_transactions_genesis'
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"dest":"V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f","role":"0","verkey":"~CoRER63DVYnWZtK8uAzNbx"},"metadata":{},"type":"1"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":1},"ver":"1"}
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"dest":"Th7MpTaRZVRYnPiabds81Y","role":"2","verkey":"~7TYfekw4GUagBnBVCqPjiC"},"metadata":{"from":"V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f"},"type":"1"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":2},"ver":"1"}
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"dest":"EbP4aYNeTHL6q385GuVpRV","role":"2","verkey":"~RHGNtfvkgPEUQzQNtNxLNu"},"metadata":{"from":"V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f"},"type":"1"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":3},"ver":"1"}
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"dest":"4cU41vWW82ArfxJxHkzXPG","role":"2","verkey":"~EMoPA6HrpiExVihsVfxD3H"},"metadata":{"from":"V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f"},"type":"1"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":4},"ver":"1"}
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"dest":"TWwCRQRZ2ZHMJFn9TzLp7W","role":"2","verkey":"~UhP7K35SAXbix1kCQV4Upx"},"metadata":{"from":"V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f"},"type":"1"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":5},"ver":"1"}
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"dest":"7JhapNNMLnwkbiC2ZmPZSE","verkey":"~LgpYPrzkB6awcHMTPZ9TVn"},"metadata":{"from":"V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f"},"type":"1"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":6},"ver":"1"}
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"dest":"MEPecrczs4Wh6FA12u519D","verkey":"~A4rMgHYboWYS1DXibCgo9W"},"metadata":{"from":"V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f"},"type":"1"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":7},"ver":"1"}
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"dest":"EAPtwgevBpzP8hkj9sxuzy","verkey":"~gmzSzu3feXC6g2djF7ar4"},"metadata":{"from":"V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f"},"type":"1"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":8},"ver":"1"}
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"dest":"LuL1HK1sDruwkfm68jrVfD","verkey":"~Nyv9BKUJuvjgMbfbwk8CFD"},"metadata":{"from":"V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f"},"type":"1"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":9},"ver":"1"}
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"dest":"462p8mtcX6jpa9ky565YEL","verkey":"~LCgq4hnSvMvB8nKd9vgsTD"},"metadata":{"from":"V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f"},"type":"1"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":10},"ver":"1"}
```

And you can see that DID `Th7MpTaRZVRYnPiabds81Y` is hardcoded on this ledger using verkey `~7TYfekw4GUagBnBVCqPjiC` which is matching what we've generated from seed `000000000000000000000000Steward1`. You can also see it's given role `"2"`. If you dig deeper, you can find in `indy-plenum`, the consensus alg. project used by indy that role ID `2` is `steward` [role](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-plenum/blob/master/plenum/common/roles.py).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer.

Comment: Hello Patrik,
We create 4 nodes and 5 clients.
Who are the 5 clients?
What is this 5th node tx about " {"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"dest":"V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f","role":"0","verkey":"~CoRER63DVYnWZtK8uAzNbx"},"metadata":{},"type":"1"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":1},"ver":"1"} " ?

Comment: @Polem That's defining the first DID created on the ledger. You can notice that all the subsequent transactions have "from: V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f", so the V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f is author of these subsequent transactons. You can also note thaat in the transaction you are pointing out the  `V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f ` DID was assigned ROLE `0` which is Trustee. If I remember right, the seed generating DID `V4SGRU86Z58d6TV7PBUe6f` is `000000000000000000000000Trustee1`

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
Yes you are right, but who's identity is that?
For example, from what I study I assume that the DID `Th7MpTaRZVRYnPiabds81Y` is the Steward for Node1, and this leads to another question. Does every node has a Steward/Observer Role?

Comment: Well, these are genesis transactions for indy pool in docker. It's supposed to be used just for development. So it's a sort of "admin" DID with high-privileged role. Afaik if you want to run node participating in the consensus, you need to own DID with Steward role. Some more info here https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Indy%20Steward . I am not sure but I think the same goes for Observer nodes/role.

Comment: So if I understand right, a Steward Role must be associate with an Indy Node. In our example, Steward1 corresponds to Node1. Node1 have a DID but the Steward1 DID is different. Steward1 DID are corresponds to the Steward1 Agent and not to the Node1 DID?

Answer (score 0):

Seed is a secret value, when we generate Indy network's genesis transaction, we use public information/keys which come from that secret seed value.

To know the write seed value, to create custom network with actors generated keys and to generate pool_transactions_genesis and domain_transactions_genesis file, you have to use indy-plenum.

You can find details on the following tutorial:

https://taseen-junaid.medium.com/hyperledger-indy-custom-network-with-indy-node-plenum-protocol-ledger-85fd10eb5bf5

You can find the code base of that tutorial into following link:

https://github.com/Ta-SeenJunaid/Hyperledger-Indy-Tutorial